# Propagate change of View dimensions to children / parents

Tags: android, view

In my Android app I want to change the height of a `RelativeLayout` in an animation. The layout contains a hierarchy of children, which are all the same size as the parent.

If I change the height of the parent view by adjusting its `LayoutParams`, the children keep their sizes. Changing the inner child's size also doesn't change the parent's size, and changing the size of all of the `View` at the same time also doesn't seem to work.

How do I increase the height of several nested views at the same time?